# Why does apt-get install django 1.6.1 on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: django, ubuntu-14.04, apt-get

I just set up a new Ubuntu 14.04 and installed django using apt-get. Now django is installed in version 1.6.1 which is an insecure and unsupported version. The end of the extended support was April 2015 (https://www.djangoproject.com/download/) so I don't see why there is such an old version in the official apt-get.

Is there a good reason for this behaviour?

Comment: Is your question *"why do the `apt-get` repositories lag the latest versions*"? It may be better suited to (or already answered on) [unix.se]. Alternatively, if you want to install a more recent version, see e.g. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-the-django-web-framework-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this belongs on another StackExchange site.

Comment: They simple do not provide a newer version of Django. Please contact Ubuntu's support if you feel that it's a security concern. The question does not belong here and I recommend using `virtualenv` to manage your Python packages instead of installing packages provided by distributions.

Comment: Possible cross-network duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/q/151283/396138

Comment: As patrys suggested, use **pip** to install Django.

Comment: I know how to setup a newer django (e.g. via pip) but I want to automate the process and would prefer to stay with apt-get so that I can just run a large apt-get command.

Answer (score 0):

I think apt-get repository is not updated for django 
Instead of using apt-get use pip to install Django(sudo pip install django). You shoud use virtualenv to run more than one python apps. Suppose you want to run more one applications,(hosting more than one django websites of different version or requirements.), run you applications in different virtualenv. Different applications may have different reuirements or version.

It's easy to install:

Install Virtualenv

```
$ pip install virtualenv
$ pip install virtualenvwrapper
$ source virtualenvwrapper.sh
$ mkvirtualenv virtualenv_name // create virtualenv
$ workon virtualenv_name
```

To restart virtalenv later
Run:

```
$ source virtualenvwrapper.sh 
$ lsvirtualenv          // list all virtual env
$ workon virtualenv_name // start working on virtual env
```

Now install you requirements on virtualenv.

```
$ pip install django==1.8
```

Try to learn here
http://www.tangowithdjango.com/book17/chapters/requirements.html#virtual-environments